# Por qué cuando selecciono un botón me imprime el texto del botón anterior, ejemplo; toco 5 y sale 4 o toco `+` y sale `-`, eso es con todos los botone

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es parte del código del programa, específicamente la ventana `JFrame` que se muestra al usuario

```
   public class cliente extends JFrame {
                JButton[] operaciones;
                JTextArea texto;
                JPanel mesaTrab, tablanum;
                ActionListener escuchaNum, escuchaOpc;
```

Este método es el oyente de los números

```
 public void grupoNum(String num) {

    JButton a = new JButton(num);

    a.addActionListener(escuchaNum);

    tablanum.add(a);

    escuchaNum = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            texto.append(a.getText());
        }
    };

}
```

Oyente de operaciones

```
  public void operaciones(String opc) {
            JButton opc1 = new JButton(opc);
    
            opc1.addActionListener(escuchaOpc);
    
            tablanum.add(opc1);
            escuchaOpc = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    texto.append(opc1.getText());
                    System.out.println(opc1.getText());
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. explica mejor tu problema, mostrar solo imágenes y código no ayuda a descubrir el problema 2. no añadas texto irrelevante a la pregunta. 3. Lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: el problema es que si presiono un boton no me muestra su texto contenido (numero) me muestra el contenido de su antecesor.  2.No muestro codigo, muestro que el 5 está presionado pero imprime 4. 3.Con ese texto "basura" era la unica forma de añadir la pregunta no sé por qué.

Comment: la advertencia te dice que debes añadir más texto para explicar tu código, edito tu pregunta para hacerla más clara, empezando por el título, por favor pon un mejor titulo.

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, y tratare de formular mejor las preguntas en el futuro :3

Comment: con el tiempo aprenderás, no estoy para obligarte a nada, solo trato de guiar. Si es posible comparte la solución para que así otras personas con problemas similares puedan saber como solucionarlo

Comment: a.addActionListener(escuchaNum); /  opc1.addActionListener(escuchaOpc); <-- estaba colocando esos metodos antes de la creación de su respectivo objeto ActionListener

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta por favor

Answer (score 3):

Solución / Error :

```java
a.addActionListener(escuchaNum); /opc1.addActionListener(escuchaOpc);
```

estaba colocando esos oyentes antes de la creación de su respectivo objeto `ActionListener`